# return seem to work for me in python 3.4

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to complete a dice game python (3.4) programming assignment for school and I'm having some trouble passing a variable from one function to another using a return statement, but when I run the program the variable "diesum" is interpreted as undefined.

```
import random

def RollDice():
    die1 = random.randint(1, 6)
    die2 = random.randint(1, 6)
    diesum = die1 + die2
    return diesum

def Craps(diesum):
    craps = [2, 3, 12]
    natural = [7, 11]
    established = [4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10]
if (diesum == craps):
    print(die1, "+", die2, "=", diesum, ",You lost")
elif (diesum == natural):
    print(die1, "+", die2, "=", diesum, ",You Win")
elif (diesum == established):
    print("Point is ", diesum)
    diesum = roll
    while diesum == roll:
        RollDice()
        if diesum == roll:
            print("Same Number, You Won!")
        elif (diesum != 7):
            print("You Win")
        else:
            print("You Lost!")
            break


RollDice()
Craps(diesum)
```

Comment: What's your actual issue?

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing the result of `RollDice` into `Craps`.  Try this instead:

```
result = RollDice()
Craps(result)
```

There are some other issues in the snippet that you have pasted, but this is the main reason that your are seeing an error.  The `return` statement returns a value from a function.  You need to bind the value to a name (`result` in my case) before you can refer to it.  You could also write `Craps(RollDice())` if you do not want to capture the result into an intermediate binding.

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons since it does not work.. first simplify the problem! This is a working initial example:

```
import random

def RollDice():
    die1 = random.randint(1, 6)
    die2 = random.randint(1, 6)
    diesum = die1 + die2
    print(diesum)
    return diesum

def Craps(diesum):
    craps = [2, 3, 12]
    natural = [7, 11]
    established = [4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10]
    for x in craps:
        if diesum == x:
            print("> You lost")
    for x in natural:
        if diesum == x:
            print("> You Win")
    for x in established:
        if diesum == x:
            print("> Point is ", diesum)


diesum = RollDice()
Craps(diesum)
```

Now write the second part of the game.. and be careful with indentation with Python!